# How to rearrange fields in user/%/edit page

Tags: forms

I have tried rearranging fields in user/edit page and I succeeded in arranging only few fields.

I cannot move user image field and timezone field. I have used [hook_form_alter](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_form_alter/7) and $form['#after_bulid'] to rearrange field but not working.

This is the code

```
function MY_MODULE_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id){
  $form['#after_build'][] = 'MY_MODULE_user_profile_form_after_build';
}
function MY_MODULE_user_profile_form_after_build($element, &$form_state) {
  $element['field_user_image']['#weight'] = '';
  $element['timezone']['#weight'] = '';
}
```

I have tried all weight from -10 to 10 but not working. Fileds should be arranged in the order as I specified in the screenshot. Can any one help me?[image]

Answer (score 1):

use nod template as **page--user--edit.tpl.php** and you can able too rearrange the fields by its machine name like as we did for content types...

just try this..

Answer (score 0):

You can use $form['#pre_render'] instead of $form['#after_bulid']

```
<?php

function MYMODULE_form_alter(&$form, $form_state, $form_id) {
  if ($form_id == 'user_profile_form') {
    $form['#pre_render'][] = 'MYMODULE_user_profile_form_pre_render';
  }
}

function MYMODULE_user_profile_form_pre_render($form) {
  $form['timezone']['#weight'] = 10;
  return $form;
}
```

Comment: This snippet works, but i can't able to move the timezone field above facebook connect as specified in the screenshot.